# Store Address book contact in sqlite titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

So i am building an application that takes contact information from the address book and stores it into a Titanium Model for use later on in the user journey.

All other information is storing and returning correctly however the image of the contact always comes back blank for some reason.

The code for storing the address book information is as follows

```
if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_AUTHORIZED){

var people = Titanium.Contacts.getAllPeople();
var totalContacts = people.length;
var addressbook = [];

Alloy.Collections.contactsModel.numberOfContacts(); 

Ti.API.info(numberOfContacts);

if(totalContacts > 0){

    var phoneContacts = [];

    for (var index = 0; index < totalContacts; index++){

        var person = people[index];

         phoneContacts.push({

            name:person.fullName,
            phoneNumber:person.phone,
            profileImage:person.image,
            contactID:person.identifier

         });


    }


Alloy.Collections.contactsModel.reset(phoneContacts);

Alloy.Collections.contactsModel.each(function(_m) {
    _m.save();
});

    }
} else if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_UNKNOWN){
    Ti.Contacts.requestAuthorization(function(e){
    //Authorization is unknown so requesting for authorization
    if (e.success) {

        } else {

        }
    });
} else {

}
}
```

The model definition is as follows

```
exports.definition = {
config: {
    columns: {
        "friendID": "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
        "contactID": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "phoneNumber": "string",
        "emailAddress": "string",
        "profileImage": "blob"
    },
    adapter: {
        type: "sql",
        collection_name: "contactsModel",
        idAttribute:"friendID"
    }
},
extendModel: function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        // extended functions and properties go here
    });

    return Model;
},
extendCollection: function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {


        collection.trigger('sync');

        },


        }

        }
        */
    });

    return Collection;
}
};
```

The image was working fine when collecting it from the address book and putting it into a list view. However when it's saved and then i attempt to retrieve it and put it into a list view where the problem occurs.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I've just worked out that it's because an image cannot be saved into SQLite DB. The way to sole it is either by turning it into a base64 string or by saving it to space and then getting the image path and storing that instead. Once I've worked out the code i'll post it so everyone can see my approach and how i've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is *not* to put all the information in the database. The reason is that when it changes on the device, those changes will not reflect in the records you've stored.

Here's how I approach it:

```js
var db = Ti.Database.open( 'person' );
db.execute( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people( " +
  "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, identifier TEXT, pid INTEGER);" );

var person = db.execute( 'SELECT id, identifier, pid FROM people' );

while( person.isValidRow( ) ) {
    var contact,
        contact_id;

    if( OS_IOS ) {
        contact_id = person.fieldByName( 'identifier' );
    }

    if( OS_ANDROID ) {
        contact_id = person.fieldByName( 'pid' );
    }

    contact = Ti.Contacts.getPersonByIdentifier( contact_id );

    var p_image = contact.image || "/images/user";

    ...
}
```

Essentially, I store the contact's ID in the database and then use that identifier to retrieve the user's info.

Note that the user's record does not always have an image, so it is a good idea to provide a default.